# How to insert record in footer of GridView using EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want in the footer of **GridView** to insert record, when I click link button it should be insert, but it's not work, I do like this: this in footer

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I have 2 textBox to be insert in footer of GridView

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TITLE") %>'/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IS_ACTIVE") %>'/>
```

Comment: If you step through the code what do you see? Does it give you any exception?

Comment: @Bayeni NO, it's not firing any exception, I think to have 'RowCommand' but how I can do it? I don't want to deal with LINQ query I want something direct to EntityDataSource, like I find control of those 2 textBox then do like this EntityDataSourceName.Insert();